# Using IN for multiple joins in a single clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

You can use **IN** to call for multiple arguments in a WHERE clause, example:

```
WHERE (i.SEGMENT1, o.ORGANIZATION_CODE)
IN (('10086','TAR'),
    ('10087','REN'),
    ('10932','RHN'));
```

Is it possible to do this in order to consolidate the number of clauses in terms of **JOINs** and **ONs**? The idea would be to present all the **JOIN tables in a list**, then IN, then a **list of ONs** such that both JOIN and ON are only **invoked 1x** with lists.

Thanks!

Comment: . . Even if this were possible, I fail to see how it would be *desirable*.  `JOIN`/`ON` syntax is quite clear.

Comment: Exactly what problem are you trying to solve? Do you want to reference a table only once for performance reasons? To reduce code "duplication"? Something else?

Comment: reduce the number of lines only. Is something like this possible?
like
FROM
table 1
JOIN
(table2,table3,table4)
ON
(table1.something=table2.something,table2.x = table3.x,table1.y = table4.y)

Comment: It is not possible, SQL language has fixed structure. And imagine: the next developer will read this long list of ONs to figure out what the hell is designed here and think why not use straightforward `join` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As they are trying to discuss JOIN, let me try to clarify it for you.

```
select
      yt.blah
   from
      yourTable yt
         JOIN ( select '10086' Seg, 'TAR' OrgCode
                union select '10087','REN'
                union select '10932','RHN' ) Parts
            on yt.Segment1 = Parts.Seg
           AND yt.Organization_Code = Parts.OrgCode
```

Notice the inner join SELECT statement preloads fixed values with the first instance of the select assigning  the column names to whatever you want.  I just abbreviated them to Seg and OrgCode.  So this can now be looked like a regular table result alias "Parts" and join to that on the entries you are interested in.  If someone needs more, just keep doing UNIONs for more rows to qualify.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle it is possible to combine a very old comma-style join with the IN operator. It would look sth like:

```
SELECT * FROM students s, courses c, enrolled e
WHERE (e.student, e.course) IN ((s.sid, c.cid));
```

However, after analyzing query plans I fear that only Oracle would be able to rewrite this query into something that could be optimized (it changed the WHERE condition into e.student=s.sid AND e.course=c.cid.)
I would not recommend using this syntax in more complex queries, because internal optimizers may simply fail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the closest you are going to get to what you are hoping for is the non-ANSI compliant "Oracle join" syntax:

```
select *
from table1,table2,table3,table4
where table1.something=table2.something
and table2.x = table3.x
and table1.y = table4.y
```

IMHO this is much harder to read and understand as queries get more complicated.

Regardless, you should have an extremely good reason not to choose easier to read/comprehend code over shorter/easier to write code.